# How to implement smart local moving algorithm?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

While Mathematica has tons of built in functionality, it can be fun / useful to implement things from scratch to ensure understanding.

In this case I am trying to implement [Smart Local Moving](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.6604).

The paper uses the Karate Club network, so lets load it:

```
G = ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph", "ZacharysKarateClub"}]
```

but prefers to use the Adjacency Matrix (AM):

```
AM = List @@@ AdjacencyMatrix[G];
```

Lets extract the Vertices and initialize the Communities (default each vertex gets its own community). Note: these implementations assume that for any graph, the vertices uses are $1,...,\lvert V\rvert$ rather than say $n,n+5, \lvert V\rvert, \lvert V\rvert + 3, ...$  (i.e. integers 1 through $\lvert V\rvert$).

```
V = Sort[VertexList@G];
Communities = Association[# -> # & /@ V];
```

### Degree of node i

```
k[AM_, i_] := \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 1\), \(Length@AM\)]\(AM[\([i, 
     j]\)]\)\);
```

### Do nodes i, j share a community

```
\[Delta][com_, i_, j_] := If[com[i] == com[j], 1, 0];
```

### Modularity

```
    modulatiry[\[ScriptCapitalG]_, com_] := Module[
  {AM = AdjacencyMatrix[\[ScriptCapitalG]], i, j, m},

  m = Length@EdgeList[\[ScriptCapitalG]];
  1/(2 m) \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i\), \(Length@AM\)]\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j\), \(Length@
       AM\)]\((AM[\([i, j]\)] - 
\*FractionBox[\(\((k[AM, i])\) \((k[AM, \ j])\)\), \(2  
          m\)])\) \[Delta][com, i, j]\)\)
  ]
```

### find best community for i

```
bestCommunity[G_, startingCommunities_, i_] := Module[
  {
   uniqueCommunities = DeleteDuplicates@Values@startingCommunities,
   tempCommunities,
   testCommunities,
   modularities,
   bestModularity
   },

  AppendTo[uniqueCommunities, 
   Max[Join[VertexList@G, {Values@startingCommunities}]] + 1];

  testCommunities = Table[
    tempCommunities = startingCommunities;
    tempCommunities[i] = uniqueCommunities[[c]];
    tempCommunities
    , {c, Length@uniqueCommunities}];


  modularities = 
   Table[modulatiry[G, testCommunities[[c]]], {c, 
     Length@testCommunities}];

  bestModularity = 
   First@First@Position[modularities, Max@modularities];

  Return[testCommunities[[bestModularity]]]
  ]
```

and a helper function

```
shuffle[list_List] := RandomSample[list, Length@list];
```

So then we can update the communities with

```
updateCommunities[G_] := Module[
  {
   coms,
   vs = shuffle[VertexList@G],
   i
   },

  For[i = 1, i <= Length@vs, i++,
    Communities = bestCommunity[G, Communities, vs[[i]]]
    ];

  ]
```

The run this

```
For[i = 1, i <= 10, i++,
 updateCommunities[\[ScriptCapitalG]];
 ]
```

Then plotting the graph we see:

```
uniqueCommunities = DeleteDuplicates@Values@Communities;
numCommunities = Length@uniqueCommunities;
vertexColors = Table[
   Style[i, 
    ColorData["Pastel"][
     First@First@
        Position[uniqueCommunities, 
         Communities[[i]]]/(numCommunities + 1)]],
   {i, Length@VertexList@\[ScriptCapitalG]}];


HighlightGraph[\[ScriptCapitalG], vertexColors]
```

we went from

[image]

to

[image]

which isnt quite right. Any advice on how to improve this?